# Visual Studio Code C# Debugging Problem (The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "dotnet" is not a file of a symlink.)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

I created a workspace using `dotnet new console`, wrote some code. But when I try to start debugging it using the option Run/Start debugging in visual studio code, it fails with the message:

> Executing task: dotnet build /home/MY USERNAME/Desktop/Codes/C#/Console/Console.csproj /property:GenerateFullPaths=true /consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary
> The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "dotnet" is not a file of a symlink.
> Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

Using the `dotnet run` command in terminal works fine without any problems. But using the start debugging option fails for some reason. I really don't want to have to type this command every time I want to start the program.

Here is the result of `dotnet --info` command:

```
.NET Core SDK (reflects global.json if exists):\
 Version:   3.1.302\
 Commit:    41faccf259

Runtime Environment:\
 OS Name:     ubuntu\
 OS Version:  20.04\
 OS Platform: Linux\
 RID:         linux-x64\
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.302/

Host (useful for support):\
  Version: 3.1.6\
  Commit:  3acd9b0cd1

.NET Core SDKs installed:\
  3.1.302 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:\
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.6 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]\
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.6 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:\
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

I've done some translating with the result, it may not match entirely the original output

Answer (score 39):

Seems like this post isn't going to be answered. I've found a way to solve it. In `tasks.json` file i replaced the command `"dotnet"` with `"/usr/bin/dotnet"` and it's working fine now. But i think that the actual problem has something to do with the path variable and my solution is just a temporary one.

Comment: Much thanks, I have had the same problem, and this totally fixed it.

Comment: To me was : /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk (Macos 10.15).

Comment: I had to use the command $ whereis dotnet, and then use the path /home/{ user }/dotnet/dotnet (Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: I had to use `/usr/local/bin/dotnet` but this was the fix for me as well. Thanks!
Edit: I am on macOS 12.5.1 btw

Comment: In the mac os terminal, I discovered where the dotnet app is using "which dotnet" command, and then, I replaced the full path on task.json as described here. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

try deleting the `.vscode` folder from the dotnet root project. Then restart the vscode project window this `.vscode` folder will regenerate automatically while you are asked to add configuration. And now your c# debugging should be working fine. It worked for me on Linux.

Comment: Worked for me on Mac 11.4 Big Sur

Comment: Nice and easy fix. However, I seem to have to redo it quite often.

Comment: Worked with VS Code on macOS 12.5.1

Answer (score 11):

This just randomly started happening on Mac for me. The fix was to add:

`export dotnet=/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet`

to my `~/.zshrc` file. Then restart vscode.

Answer (score 4):

Here the issue was the dotnet package had just been installed and added to the path on Mac (using .net 5.0).  I had to exit vs-code, close the terminal I had launched it from using `code .` and then open a new terminal tab (where dotnet itself was resolvable) and then relaunch vs-code from that new terminal.

TLDR launch new terminal after dotnet install then use `code .` to launch new vs code instance from there (assumes you used the Ctrl/Cmd+shift+p "Add to shell" option in vscode to launch from a terminal)

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check this [Grepper response](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/csharp/The+terminal+process+failed+to+launch%3A+Path+to+shell+executable+%22dotnet%22+is+not+a+file+or+a+symlink.), works well on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS also.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone else having this issue, you are likely experiencing a bug with VSCode, which will hopefully be resolved soon:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/158666

You likely have a `~/dotnet` folder, and if your vscode process starts in the home directory, the folder will take priority over the executable in PATH.

Check the other answers for temporary workarounds until the fix is merged.

EDIT:

Just because there is so much conflicting information here, the fixes that should work are:

- Changing the `"command"` field in tasks.json from `"dotnet"` to the full path (e.g. `"/usr/bin/dotnet"`)

Or

- Starting vscode via a terminal using `code .` (as long as you run this in a directory which doesn't contain a `dotnet` sub-directory)

Answer (score 1):

In `.zshrc` I had to change

```
export dotnet=/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
```

to

```
export dotnet=/usr/local/share/dotnet
```

I have a dotnet executable within my dotnet folder too, but it only works if I do not include it in the path.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, and I tried to solve it as suggested, but when I restarted the pc it was back to being misconfigured.
So I found out that there is dotnet 3.1 in the snap repository.

this command shows all dotnet sdks

```
snap info dotnet-sdk
```

and to install dotnet 3.1 use this command

```
sudo snap install dotnet-sdk --channel=3.1/stable --classic
```

now it's working fine for me

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is check path of the dotnet where it bound to.
Use the command.

```
ls -la /usr/local/bin
```

It will show the dotnet path used [image: see the dotnet path and check if it a valid path].

If the path is incorrect please use the command

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet  /usr/local/bin/
```

Instead of '/usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet' add your correct path.
You can get the correct dotnet path by:

```
whereis dotnet
```

Don't forget to add '/dotnet' at the end of the path you get from using the above command.

Answer (score 0):

In [LINUX] the $PATH environment variable may have another path to the "dotnet" command. So, you can use "echo $PATH" command to check it. If it's true, then you can check the bash file "sudo nano /etc/bash.bashrc" and remove the export with "dotnet" note.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling dotnet and vscode did not work for me, nor did removing `~/.vscode`

Eventually I resolved the issue by removing this directory `~/.config/Code`. That directory contains various settings so you may wish to back it up / you may wish to retain your `settings.json` file.

There is probably a specific value somewhere in that directory that causes this particular issue but I didn't want to sift through it to find the culprit - probably easier to just start again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case issue resolved by installing dotnet 5 sdk from the link below and **Restarting the MAC**.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-5.0.300-macos-x64-installer?journey=vs-code

Answer (score 0):

The solution may be that you installed .NET using the default instructions using export `DOTNET_ROOT` etc, and putting that in `~/bashrc`
The best way is, to install `.NET SDK` using

```
sudo apt install 
sudo apt-get update; \
sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
sudo apt-get update && \
sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-5.0
```

Full instructions on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu.

Now, .net install will indeed involve a 'symlink' about which the debugger complained. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the "dotnet" folder from my personal folder and it worked. Apparently, when I downloaded the SDK, I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes in the settings.json file (typically in ~/.config/Code/User dir).

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
       "bash" : { 
           "path" : "/bin/bash", 
           "icon" : "terminal-bash"
          }
        }
}
```

PS: Using Ubuntu 20.04. Neither removing ~/.config/Code nor removing ~/.vscode worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Old post but may help somebody:

I have had this issue when VScode is re-launched after a restart of my mac.
Closing vscode and re-opening it gives access back to the shell.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem too. I am a MacOS user. Unfortunately, there are two dotnet as located in two folders on my computer. This situation confused VSCode working style. Normally dotnet should be in **/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet** location. I had dotnet in **/usr/local/bin/dotnet/dotnet** folder as well. I removed the second location then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after upgrading my vs code to Version: 1.85.0 (MACOS).

This fixed the issue for me.

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet  /usr/local/bin/
```

PS. I restarted my vs code after the linking above. I am not sure if restarting vs code is need or not.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?